# set the nameserver of my hosting on the settings of my domain

Tags: dns, nameservers

I have a problem with the setup of my domain, to be able to use it with the nameservers of my host.
this is the control panel of my domain name:
[image]
immediately after confirming the settings the site of my domain (register.it), warned me to wait 24 / 48h for the propagation of the domain, but for some reason, after this time, the migration of the domain on my hosting has been canceled .
the support advised me to perform a test to check for any problems, the feedback was this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<dnsValidator:result xmlns:dnsValidator="it.nic.dns.validator" version="2.0">
    <domain>miodominio.it.</domain>
    <status>FAILED</status>
    <validationId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</validationId>
    <validationDate>2018-05-07T16:48:00.681+02:00</validationDate>
    <nameservers>
        <nameserver name="ns5.xxxxx.net.">
            <address type="IPv4">ip.ns5.xxx.xxx</address>
        </nameserver>
        <nameserver name="ns6.xxxxx.net.">
            <address type="IPv4">ip.ns6.xxx.xxx</address>
        </nameserver>
    </nameservers>
    <tests>
        <test name="NameserversResolvableTest" status="SUCCEEDED">
            <nameserver name="ns5.xxxxx.net." status="SUCCEEDED"/>
            <nameserver name="ns6.xxxxx.net." status="SUCCEEDED"/>
        </test>
        <test name="IPCompareTest" status="SUCCEEDED">
            <nameserver name="ns5.xxxxx.net." status="SUCCEEDED"/>
            <nameserver name="ns6.xxxxx.net." status="SUCCEEDED"/>
        </test>
        <test name="SOAQueryAnswerTest" status="FAILED">
            <nameserver name="ns5.xxxxx.net." status="FAILED">
                <detail status="FAILED" queryId="1">'REFUSED' returncode</detail>
            </nameserver>
            <nameserver name="ns6.xxxxx.net." status="FAILED">
                <detail status="FAILED" queryId="2">'REFUSED' returncode</detail>
            </nameserver>
        </test>
        <test name="SOAMasterCompareTest" status="WARNING">
            <nameserver name="ns5.xxxxx.net." status="WARNING">
                <detail queryId="1">Test skipped for 'REFUSED' returncode</detail>
            </nameserver>
            <nameserver name="ns6.xxxxx.net." status="WARNING">
                <detail queryId="2">Test skipped for 'REFUSED' returncode</detail>
            </nameserver>
        </test>
        <test name="IPSoaTest" skipped="true"/>
        <test name="NSQueryAnswerTest" status="FAILED">
            <nameserver name="ns5.xxxxx.net." status="FAILED">
                <detail status="FAILED" queryId="3">'REFUSED' returncode</detail>
            </nameserver>
            <nameserver name="ns6.xxxxx.net." status="FAILED">
                <detail status="FAILED" queryId="4">'REFUSED' returncode</detail>
            </nameserver>
        </test>
        <test name="NSCompareTest" status="WARNING">
            <nameserver name="ns5.xxxxx.net." status="WARNING">
                <detail queryId="3">Test skipped for 'REFUSED' returncode</detail>
            </nameserver>
            <nameserver name="ns6.xxxxx.net." status="WARNING">
                <detail queryId="4">Test skipped for 'REFUSED' returncode</detail>
            </nameserver>
        </test>
        <test name="NSCountTest" status="WARNING">
            <nameserver name="ns5.xxxxx.net." status="WARNING">
                <detail queryId="3">Test skipped for 'REFUSED' returncode</detail>
            </nameserver>
            <nameserver name="ns6.xxxxx.net." status="WARNING">
                <detail queryId="4">Test skipped for 'REFUSED' returncode</detail>
            </nameserver>
        </test>
        <test name="MXQueryAnswerTest" status="FAILED">
            <nameserver name="ns5.xxxxx.net." status="FAILED">
                <detail status="FAILED" queryId="5">'REFUSED' returncode</detail>
            </nameserver>
            <nameserver name="ns6.xxxxx.net." status="FAILED">
                <detail status="FAILED" queryId="6">'REFUSED' returncode</detail>
            </nameserver>
        </test>
        <test name="MXCompareTest" status="WARNING">
            <nameserver name="ns5.xxxxx.net." status="WARNING">
                <detail queryId="5">Test skipped for 'REFUSED' returncode</detail>
            </nameserver>
            <nameserver name="ns6.xxxxx.net." status="WARNING">
                <detail queryId="6">Test skipped for 'REFUSED' returncode</detail>
            </nameserver>
        </test>
        <test name="MXRecordIsPresentTest" status="WARNING">
            <nameserver name="ns5.xxxxx.net." status="WARNING">
                <detail queryId="5">Test skipped for 'REFUSED' returncode</detail>
            </nameserver>
            <nameserver name="ns6.xxxxx.net." status="WARNING">
                <detail queryId="6">Test skipped for 'REFUSED' returncode</detail>
            </nameserver>
        </test>
        <test name="CNAMEHostTest" status="WARNING"/>
    </tests>
    <queries>
        <query id="1">
            <queryFor>miodominio.it.</queryFor>
            <type>SOA</type>
            <destination>ns5.xxxxx.net./[ip.ns5.xxx.xxx]</destination>
            <result>
;; - HEADER - opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 34408
;; flags: qr ; qd: 1 an: 0 au: 0 ad: 0 
;; QUESTIONS:
;; miodominio.it., type = SOA, class = IN

;; ANSWERS:

;; Message size: 32 bytes</result>
        </query>
        <query id="2">
            <queryFor>miodominio.it.</queryFor>
            <type>SOA</type>
            <destination>ns6.xxxxx.net./[ip.ns6.xxx.xxx]</destination>
            <result>
;; - HEADER - opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 47175
;; flags: qr ; qd: 1 an: 0 au: 0 ad: 0 
;; QUESTIONS:
;; miodominio.it., type = SOA, class = IN

;; ANSWERS:

;; Message size: 32 bytes</result>
        </query>
        <query id="3">
            <queryFor>miodominio.it.</queryFor>
            <type>NS</type>
            <destination>ns5.xxxxx.net./[ip.ns5.xxx.xxx]</destination>
            <result>
;; - HEADER - opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 12662
;; flags: qr ; qd: 1 an: 0 au: 0 ad: 0 
;; QUESTIONS:
;; miodominio.it., type = NS, class = IN

;; ANSWERS:

;; Message size: 32 bytes</result>
        </query>
        <query id="4">
            <queryFor>miodominio.it.</queryFor>
            <type>NS</type>
            <destination>ns6.xxxxx.net./[ip.ns6.xxx.xxx]</destination>
            <result>
;; - HEADER - opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 41267
;; flags: qr ; qd: 1 an: 0 au: 0 ad: 0 
;; QUESTIONS:
;; miodominio.it., type = NS, class = IN

;; ANSWERS:

;; Message size: 32 bytes</result>
        </query>
        <query id="5">
            <queryFor>miodominio.it.</queryFor>
            <type>MX</type>
            <destination>ns5.xxxxx.net./[ip.ns5.xxx.xxx]</destination>
            <result>
;; - HEADER - opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 17519
;; flags: qr ; qd: 1 an: 0 au: 0 ad: 0 
;; QUESTIONS:
;; miodominio.it., type = MX, class = IN

;; ANSWERS:

;; Message size: 32 bytes</result>
        </query>
        <query id="6">
            <queryFor>miodominio.it.</queryFor>
            <type>MX</type>
            <destination>ns6.xxxxx.net./[ip.ns6.xxx.xxx]</destination>
            <result>
;; - HEADER - opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 7640
;; flags: qr ; qd: 1 an: 0 au: 0 ad: 0 
;; QUESTIONS:
;; miodominio.it., type = MX, class = IN

;; ANSWERS:

;; Message size: 32 bytes</result>
        </query>
        <query id="7">
            <queryFor>ns5.xxxxx.net.</queryFor>
            <type>A</type>
            <destination>local resolver</destination>
            <result>
;; - HEADER - opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 12806
;; flags: qr rd ra ; qd: 1 an: 1 au: 2 ad: 0 
;; QUESTIONS:
;; ns5.xxxxx.net., type = A, class = IN

;; ANSWERS:
ns5.xxxxx.net. 300 IN A ip.ns5.xxx.xxx

;; Message size: 106 bytes</result>
        </query>
        <query id="8">
            <queryFor>ns5.xxxxx.net.</queryFor>
            <type>AAAA</type>
            <destination>local resolver</destination>
            <result>
;; - HEADER - opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45034
;; flags: qr rd ra ; qd: 1 an: 0 au: 1 ad: 0 
;; QUESTIONS:
;; ns5.xxxxx.net., type = AAAA, class = IN

;; ANSWERS:

;; Message size: 97 bytes</result>
        </query>
        <query id="9">
            <queryFor>ns6.xxxxx.net.</queryFor>
            <type>A</type>
            <destination>local resolver</destination>
            <result>
;; - HEADER - opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17569
;; flags: qr rd ra ; qd: 1 an: 1 au: 2 ad: 2 
;; QUESTIONS:
;; ns6.xxxxx.net., type = A, class = IN

;; ANSWERS:
ns6.xxxxx.net. 300 IN A ip.ns6.xxx.xxx

;; Message size: 150 bytes</result>
        </query>
        <query id="10">
            <queryFor>ns6.xxxxx.net.</queryFor>
            <type>AAAA</type>
            <destination>local resolver</destination>
            <result>
;; - HEADER - opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10406
;; flags: qr rd ra ; qd: 1 an: 0 au: 1 ad: 0 
;; QUESTIONS:
;; ns6.xxxxx.net., type = AAAA, class = IN

;; ANSWERS:

;; Message size: 97 bytes</result>
        </query>
    </queries>
</dnsValidator:result>
```

could someone help me understand the results? what were the problems? Do you have any advice on how to solve?
thanks so much!!

Comment: 1) you are offtopic here, see instead Webmasters or ServerFault 2) When providing error messages, use English, with text and not an image. 3) when you set nameservers authoritative for a domain you do not need to specify their IP only their names (except in specific cases of glue) and more important 4) stop doing useless obfuscation and give the true names involved if you want relevant help. Also: 5) propagation is a misnommer in DNS and 24/48h are not really relevant. + Use online tools to troubleshoot: Zonemaster, DNSViz.

Comment: i didn't pay any attention to the section sorry, anyway i tried also with zonemaster and dnsviz and the results its not so much different, anyway now I'll try to repost the question in the right section, uncensored and with the results of the other test, thanks so much!

Comment: Followup in https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/115003/set-the-nameserver-of-my-hosting-on-the-settings-of-my-domain  ; please close your question here or mark it solved or something.